# Vuetify : Editable cell for v-data-table in specified column only

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have this simple record in vuetify using v-data-table.

[image]

I'm making an editable cell for adding data. So once you *clicked* any column cell, a popup edit will appear to edit the data.

But, I don't want the user to edit this on this **No** and **Name** column, because it is a fixed data.

All I want is to edit only this **Result** column(adding data in cell).
[image]

How could I achieve that function?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/neyubee/pen/poxbGVP)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
        headers: [{text: 'No', sortable: false, value: 'number'},
              {text: 'Name', sortable: false, value: 'name'},
              {text: 'Result', sortable: false, value:'result'}],
        records: [{name:'data 1'},{name:'data 2'},{name:'data 3'}],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    itemsWithIndex() {
      return this.records.map(
        (records, index) => ({
          ...records,
          number: index + 1
        }))
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 1rem;
}

#table-card {
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.1.12/vuetify.min.css" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.1.12/vuetify.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        <v-card id="table-card">
        <h3>Records</h3>
        <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="itemsWithIndex"/>
        <template
        v-for="header in headers"
        v-slot:[`item.${header.value}`]="props"
        >
        <v-edit-dialog
            :key="header.value"
            :return-value.sync="props.item[header.value]"
        >
            {{ props.item[header.value] }}
            <template v-slot:input>
            <v-text-field
                v-model="props.item[header.value]"
                label="Edit"
                single-line
            ></v-text-field>
            </template>
        </v-edit-dialog>
        </template>
        </v-card>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: In the column template `#item.result="{item}"` you will include [v-edit-dialog](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#edit-dialog) as [demonstrated](https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=101) in the Vuetify documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are setting an edit dialog on all cells:

```html
<template
  v-for="header in headers"
  v-slot:[`item.${header.value}`]="props"
>
  <v-edit-dialog
    :key="header.value"
    :return-value.sync="props.item[header.value]"
  >
...
```

Instead, set it only on the result column:

```html
<template v-slot:item.result="{item, header}">
  <v-edit-dialog
    :key="header.value"
    :return-value.sync="item[header.value]"
  >
...
```

Alternatively, if you only want to exclude a few columns, leave the `v-for`, but have it iterate a filtered list of headers.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
        headers: [{text: 'No', sortable: false, value: 'number'},
              {text: 'Name', sortable: false, value: 'name'},
              {text: 'Result', sortable: false, value:'result'}],
        records: [{name:'data 1'},{name:'data 2'},{name:'data 3'}],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    itemsWithIndex() {
      return this.records.map(
        (records, index) => ({
          ...records,
          number: index + 1
        }))
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 1rem;
}

#table-card {
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.1.12/vuetify.min.css" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.1.12/vuetify.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        <v-card id="table-card">
        <h3>Records</h3>
        <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="itemsWithIndex"/>
        <template v-slot:item.result="{item, header}">
        <v-edit-dialog
            :key="header.value"
            :return-value.sync="item[header.value]"
        >
            {{ item[header.value] }}
            <template v-slot:input>
            <v-text-field
                v-model="item[header.value]"
                label="Edit"
                single-line
            ></v-text-field>
            </template>
        </v-edit-dialog>
        </template>
        </v-card>
    </v-app>
</div>
```